# scanf() function failure

Tags: c, scanf

I installed the MingW C compiler and I am trying to compile and run a C program there.
I use Visual Stdio Code IDE.
OS is WINDOWS 10.
Compiler is MinGW.

My programs that do not use `scanf()` or `gets()` all run successfully but  when I use `scanf()` function the program does not take input. I also used `gets()` function but that has the same problem. So when I press "run" button it does not give any output.

Here is my minimal reproducible example.  Is this a compiler problem or is my code wrong?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
     
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    //scanf("%d", &n); 
}
```

OUTPUT for the above code is:

```
[Running] cd "d:\code\C\" && gcc #13sum.c -o #13sum && "d:\code\C\"#13sum
Enter a number: 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.29 seconds
```

---

If I add a `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
     
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);  
}
```

OUTPUT for the above code is:

```
[Running] cd "d:\code\C\" && gcc #13sum.c -o #13sum && "d:\code\C\"#13sum
[Done] exited with code=1 in 31.526 seconds
```

After using `fflush(stdout);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
   fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &n);  
}
```

```
[Running] cd "d:\code\C\" && gcc #13sum.c -o #13sum && "d:\code\C\"#13sum
Enter a number: 
[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.804 seconds
```

After using `fflush(stdout);` printf() statement is executed but now I am unable to enter the value. I am typing but it is not showing in the output .
Compiler is not any giving errors in any of the above case.

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you compile? Run?

Comment: "not working"  is not a useful problem description. What is the specific error or incorrect behaviour?

Comment: "you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means."

Comment: How are you running your program? How are you compiling it? What parameters? Do you use IDE? You code looks correct, but without more information we can't help you!

Comment: You need to check the value returned by `scanf` so you can detect end of input, and `%d` can lead to undefined behavior if the input cannot be represented by an int, but otherwise your code seems fine.  It works for me.  What output do you get on input `1 2 3 0`?  I get 4 prompts and "Sum is = 6", as expected.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion would be lessened if you flush the output after printing the prompt.  As it is, when you run it interactively you may not see the prompt due to buffering.  (ie, `printf("Enter a number: "); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: As William says, it's likely your runtime environment closes standard input stream.  What happens when you run your program normally (from a shell)?  What value does `scanf()` return?  I can't explain why you're getting a return value of `1` in the second case, though - `main()` defaults to returning 0...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your compiler its working fine for me.
your code take input until you enter 0 and then print the sum.
here's my output:-

`Enter a number: 45 Enter a number: 34 Enter a number: 0 Sum is = 79%`
so, check if you installed your mingw C compiler properly [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html).